# Share LAN connection over internet

Tags: vlan

I have a LAN network in **location A** with some *laptop 1* and *laptop 2* connected to it.

I have a *laptop 3* in **location B**.

*Laptop 1, laptop 2 and laptop 3* will be connected to the internet.

Is it possible for laptop 3 to access the LAN network using the internet from **location B** ? (Assuming I have access to laptops only in **Location A** and do not have access to any network infrastructure).

Thanks,
Sash

Comment: If the answer helped you, then you should accept it so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's possible using **VPN**.

You need in **location A** a home router with a built-in VPN server. You can then use your router’s web interface to activate and configure the VPN server.

Check if your existing router has a built-in VPN server. Otherwise, buy a new one or check if your router can be flashed with `DD-WRT`or `OpenWrt`.

if you flash your router, you are replacing the router’s standard operating system with a new one. and get a built-in VPN server support, so you can host a VPN server even on routers that don’t come with VPN server software.

Be sure to pick up a supported router — or check your current router to see if it’s supported by DD-WRT. Flash the third-party firmware and enable the VPN server.

On **laptop 3** you will need to configure the VPN connection in:

```
Settings  > Network & Internet  > VPN > Add a VPN connection.
```

Comment: Just a reminder that home networking is better discussed on [su].

Answer (score 0):

Laptop 3 in location C can access resources in location A & B through Site -Site VPN tunnel build between location C & A & B .. There are two option available .

1 ) Configuring site to site vpn tunnel between locations and route LAN traffic through  tunnel

2. .Connecting sites through MPLS point to point leased line and enable routing such that Lan tràffic passed through links.